# A little confused about a potential analysis question

Tags: poisson-regression

This is my first time asking a question here, I have two sets of count data that I want to compare to one another.  One set has an excess amount of zeros, while the other does not.  My first idea was to use a Zero-Inflated Poisson regression for the first set of data with the excess amount of zeros within it, and then either a normal or quasi Poisson depending on the second set depending upon the existence of over-dispersion in the data.  Is this a good approach or would it be better to use one analysis for both sets of data?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare to one another"?  Do you want to look at shape of distribution, measures of location/central tendency?  Particular quantiles? Or what?

Comment: I am sorry I want to determine if similar associations exist between the data.  I am looking at two similar diseases and comparing it to the same environmental features.

Answer (score 0):

So, from your comments, you have two diseases and you want to compare how they relate to a bunch of environmental variables.

If this is right, then you can simply use logistic regression on both data sets. There is no need for a count model because the dependent variable is not a count, it's a probability.

Comment: Your last statement is mysterious.  The OP clearly indicates the dependent data are counts.  In what sense, then, are you claiming these are "probabilities"?

Comment: Reading the OP's reply to my comment on the post, it's clear that the question was confused.  OP does not want to compare the distributions but the regressions.